# Symfony 4 Doctrine with @ORM\Column throws MySQL 1054 error

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm adding new field to the existing database. To avoid some problems I used built in symfony commands `bin/console make:entity`, `bin/console make:migration` and `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute <migration_id>`

First i used `bin/console make:entity FirebaseToken`

```
Your entity already exists! So let's add some new fields!

 New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > token_source

 Field type (enter ? to see all types) [string]:
 > 

 Field length [255]:
 > 45

 Can this field be null in the database (nullable) (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes

 updated: src/Entity/FirebaseToken.php

 Add another property? Enter the property name (or press <return> to stop adding fields):
 > 



  Success! 


 Next: When you're ready, create a migration with make:migration
```

In `FirebaseToken` Entity it's generated

```
    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
     private $token_source;
```

with setters and getters.
After that I run `in/console make:migration` to make migration, did check it and it was as expected. Run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute <migration_id>` to update database with this change.

Next thing i run my tests that were passing before adding this column. Only change was in controller that I used this setter `setTokenSource()`
Tests failed with message

```
"An exception occurred while executing \'INSERT INTO firebase_token (token_string, last_seen_on, token_source, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)\' with params ["some-long-firebase-token", "2019-05-24 08:51:53", "web", 176346]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column \'token_source\' in \'field list\'"
```

The error message is self explained. I did check database, filed is there, created as expected. If I run this query directly from mysql workbench, query executes without errors.

If I remove annotations from the new field in Entity `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=45, nullable=true)` and run my tests, they pass without any error.

I used everything to avoid "human error effect" but yet it doesn't work. I even tried recreating whole database from scratch in my test env, and still nothing. Why is this happening ?

Using MySQL 5.7.26

PHP 7.1.29

Symfony 4.2

Comment: Whats the structure of the other fields in FirebaseToken Entity? $token_source or $tokenSource (CamelCase vs underscore)?

Comment: maybe a very dumb question, but do the tests use the same database as the one used in the migrations?

Comment: @Chris i used base underscore as it is in the database. Other fields are token_string, last_seen_on, user_id and id

Comment: @Jakumi yes. Test were run on the same database.

Comment: You say it's the same database. The error message (unless you gave us the wrong one) clearly states, that you want to access a field that doesn't exist. You say it does in fact exist. Now, I'm sorry to tell you that at least one of those three statements cannot be true..

Comment: Tests typically run with APP_ENV=test, but console commands default to APP_ENV=dev. Did you run `APP_ENV=test php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`?

Answer (score 0):

First delete migrations table and directory. 
After: 
1- php bin/console make:migration 
2- php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate